# Explaining how to translate spanish "Ya" (already vs just vs ...)

Tags: translation, spanish

I asked my coworker to fix something in a program.  When he fixed it, he replied with, "I already fixed it." -- this wasn't intentionally misleading, but was an incorrect translation of "ya".  But for a moment I was thinking... "no, you fixed it *after* I asked".  It was a bit jarring.

Having learned a decent bit of Spanish when I was younger, I paused and realized there was some confusion when translating between "ya" and "already".

BUT...I really struggled to find a clear/cogent explanation to help my coworker--from my English perspective.  I finally found an article *in Spanish*, but honestly it was crazy how many meanings of "ya" there were, many of which I hadn't realized, and it was slow-going to read through it and make sense of it.  My Spanish skills are rusty.  So *nobody else whose primary language was English was likely to realize what happened, had they seen this mistake*

So, here's my question: **How can I help both the ESL coworker, other coworkers, and others in general to be aware of this pitfall, and what is a kind, cogent, and English-centric way to explain it?**

Thanks.

- *Secondary question: And are there blogs/references or sites where I can learn more patterns of this sort of mis-translation across many languages? As a privileged white guy from a homogenous suburbia in the USA, I probably have a number of ways I might misunderstand cultural differences, and likely need to improve my awareness bit by bit.*

Comment: _Ya_ is awfully close to English "right now". It's idioms that do it for me; _Ya vengo_, literally 'I already go' really means "I'll be right back".

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Are you saying that Spanish would use "ya" in all 3 cases?

Comment: Note that "just" can also be used to mean "only". "I just took out the trash (but not the recycling)."

Comment: Although in English, "already" can colloquially mean "right now" if not "in near the future". [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14530/what-exactly-does-already-mean-when-used-in-the-imperative-mood).

Comment: The easiest way is to use examples, and translate these phrases in their first language. **Have you done the task?** A. *No, not yet*. B. *I've already done it*. C. **I've *just* done it**. Point out that "just" is a better fit, it means the task was *recently* completed. (I wanted to post this an answer, and expand on it but then I discovered the question was closed) A similar issue arises with Italian speakers who confuse *già* (already)  with *just* because the two words share the same "dʒ" sound.

Comment: When he fixed it, he replied with, "I already fixed it." -- this wasn't intentionally misleading, but was an incorrect translation of "ya". No, the translation is correct.  Ya lo arreglé.=I [have] already fixed it. I have just fixed it.= Acabo de arreglarlo.

Comment: Ya vengo. I'm coming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better suited for [languagelearning.SE]